# curve() works in the first example but not the second, but they look identical. Why?

Tags: r, function, plot, statistics, normal-distribution

I'm new to R and try to do some exercises. I wonder why the first code works fine while the second code doesn't. When I try to run the second code, it says he can't find function `a`.

1.)

```
x = seq(from = - 9, to = 9, len = 100)
curve(dnorm(x,0,2),add = FALSE, from = -9, to = 9)
```

2.)

```
x = seq(from = - 9, to = 9, len = 100)
a = dnorm(x,0,2)
curve(a,add = FALSE, from = -9, to = 9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `curve` is always puzzling. Look at `?curve` on its first argument `expr`, as well as the "Details" section.

In fact, you misunderstood the first (working) case.

```
curve(dnorm(x, 0, 2), from = 9, to = 9)
```

does not use the `x` you gave: `seq(-9, 9, length = 100)`, but choses sampling points **internally**. See argument `n` of `curve`. Here, you are passing `curve` a function of **formal** argument `x`, not a real-valued vector, as `a` in your second (failing) case.

If you don't believe this, let's change line displaying to point displaying:

```
curve(dnorm(x, 0, 2), n = 10, from = -9, to = 9, type = "p")
```

You see? There are only 10 points on the graph, even if you have preset `x <- seq(-9, 9, len = 100)`.

Another supplementary example is to tweak with `xname`. Let's use another variable, say `foo`.

```
curve(dnorm(foo, 0, 2), from = -9, to = 9, xname = "foo")
```

There is no variable `foo` in this R session, but the above code works. Because `xname` tells `curve` that `foo` is a formal variable.